# Dynamically loading playlist array into video.js with proper formatting

Tags: javascript, arrays, video.js

I'm making a playlist of videos using two plugins; [video-js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) and [videojs-playlist](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist). They require playlists to be formatted like this, and will load the videos onto the player:

```
player.playlist([{
  sources: [{
    src: 'https://someurl',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }],
}, {
  sources: [{
    src: 'https://someurl',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }],
}]);
```

I dynamically call urls with ajax, and then use the `player.playlist` feature. It looks like this:

```
var videosrc = [];    
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.courses[0].videos.length; i++) {
        var vidsUrl = response.data.courses[0].videos[i].videoUrl
        videosrc.push({sources: [{src: vidsUrl, type: 'video/mp4'}]});
});
player.playlist(videosrc);
```

I `console.log` `vidsUrl` or use `player.playlist(videosrc)` in the console and they both look like this:

[Javascript Array Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09uZo.png)

That seems correct, but I still don't think that it perfectly matches the exact `player.playlist` requirements. How would I be able to see how it's interpreted by the plugin, because all I know is the way the chrome console formats it.

All that happens right now is that the first video loads and plays, but nothing else does, and it just repeats when you advance videos.

Comment: Are you getting an error or other? Also, you will need to set the player.playlist within the ajax done function as well. you are making that call asynchronously which means the player.playlist(videosrc); could execute well before your ajax call is done causing you to have a blank array set.

Comment: @basic Hey, sorry for the delay (exams). You solved it! Dumb mistake on my part, needed to put the `player.playlist` within the done function because it was being called too early. Doesn't explain how the first video would load though.

Comment: glad I could help!